# Out of nowhere, SQL Conversion error on a simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

On a system which has worked fine for years - just today I'm noticing an error.

The mind-blowingly simple

```
SELECT InvoiceID
FROM t_Invoices
WHERE DocumentNumber = 3841734
```

is now giving an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3841730.' to data type int.

I have no idea where the 3841730 value is coming from (although its suspiciously close to the DocumentNumber value - 3841734)
I am only selecting InvoiceID so why is it giving this error.

All the data for this row is as follows:

```
InvoiceID   DocumentNumber  Date_Created    IsActive    Date_LastOperated   Date_Closed WF_CurrentState WF_PreviousState    WF_CurrentUser  WF_CurrentCredDeptUser  WF_InitialCredDeptUser  WF_PreviousUser WF_WithCreditorsDept    ApprovedAboveLimit  Approved    DocumentSpec    CostCentreID    Date_Due    PaymentInterestComment  PaymentInterestFlag PaymentInterestCommentFreeText  DocumentSpecOriginal
832128  3841734 2021-04-23 08:57:05.000 1   2021-04-23 08:57:05.000 NULL    1   1   15  15  15  15  1   0   0   \\invoicerouting\DocumentStore\2021\04-Apr\UP-20210423-3841734.pdf  1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would appear to be causing the problem:

```
WHERE DocumentNumber = 3841734
```

The issue is that you are mixing types.  In this case, `DocumentNumber` would appear to be a *string* not a number.  And, SQL (all dialects) prefer numbers to strings, so it attempts to convert the column `DocumentNumber` to a string.

The value:

```
3841730.
```

is a value in the column.  You may or may not notice, but it appears to have a decimal point.  Oh, how sad.

You *should* fix the data.  But in the meantime, fix the query!  Don't mix data types:

```
WHERE DocumentNumber = '3841734'
```

What can you do to fix the data?  First, find offending values:

```
select DocumentNumber
from t_Invoices
where try_convert(int, DocumentNumber) is null and DocumentNumber is not null;
```

After you have fixed the data, you can then do one of two things:

1. If you decide that you really want a string, then add a check constraint to only allow digits (or whatever is allowed).
2. If you decide that the value is really a number, then change the type to `int` -- or if you need larger values, to a numeric.

I would go for (2).  A distinguishing feature for (1) would be if leading zeros are important.

Comment: Worth noting, to the OP, that `'3841730.'` and `'3841730'` will *not* be seen as equal, so they may get unexpected results when trying to the row(s) with the value `'3841730.'`. As such fixing the design is the only *real* solution here.

Comment: Also, the `WHERE` for finding should have `AND DocumentNumber IS NOT NULL`; otherwise it'll just return rows where `DocumentNumber` has the value `NULL`.

Comment: @Gordon you sir are an absolute lifesaver. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Just to follow up when I try to fix the data I get "'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @PeteWhelan `TRY_CONVERT` is available in every supported version of SQL Server, and also those in extended support. Are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server? If so, you should really highlight that in the question as users here will always assume you are using supported software unless you explicitly state otherwise. SQL Server 2008 has been entirely unsupported for almost 2 years now, so it's long past time you got your instance upgraded. If you are using 2012+ then your database is still in a compatibility level of 100 of less; you should probably have increased that by now too.

Comment: Its SQL Server 2012

Comment: @PeteWhelan . . . You might have your compatibility set to an earlier version.  You can instead use `where DocumentNumber like '%[^0-9]%'`.